# HTTP API Request for Brandwatch php

Tags: php, arrays, api, httprequest

With an API Request a get a Server response in JSOn like this in one String:

```
{"resultsTotal":3,"resultsPage":-1,"resultsPageSize":-1,"results":[{"id":1998425622,"name":"Regionale Mentions_Branche","type":"search string","creationDate":"2015-08-21T15:13:58.226+0000","lastModificationDate":"2015-08-21T15:13:58.226+0000","lastModifiedUsername":"mueller@cybay.de","lockedQuery":false,"lockedByUsername":null},{"id":1998422533,"name":"HTP_Sponsoring","type":"search string","creationDate":"2015-08-18T08:53:38.136+0000","lastModificationDate":"2015-08-18T08:53:38.136+0000","lastModifiedUsername":"mueller@cybay.de","lockedQuery":false,"lockedByUsername":null},{"id":1998422529,"name":"HTP_Brand Mentions","type":"search string","creationDate":"2015-08-18T08:41:32.699+0000","lastModificationDate":"2015-08-18T14:42:19.977+0000","lastModifiedUsername":"mueller@cybay.de","lockedQuery":false,"lockedByUsername":null}]}
```

so I use the json_decode to get an array.

now i want to parse the array because i only need the "id":xxxxxxxx and the "name"
my code is:

```
$webservice = 'http://newapi.brandwatch.com/projects/';
$kundenId = $_POST["kunden"];
$key = "?access_token=XXXXXXXXX";
$onlySdate = $_POST["startdate"];
$onlyEdate = $_POST["enddate"];
$startdate = "&startDate=".$onlySdate ;
$enddate = "?endDate=" .$onlyEdate ;
$url = $webservice . $kundenId . "/queries/summary".$key;

$domainRequest = $url;
//header("Location:$domainRequest");
$data = array();

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
                                'Authorization: Basic ' . BASIC_AUTH,
        'method' => 'GET',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($domainRequest, false, $context);

$array = json_decode($result, true);

//echo count ($result);
//echo "<br>";
print_r ($array);
```

if i want to receive just one entry of the array i get no response or without the true in `json_decode ($result);` i'll get a Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /data/kunden/cylab/BH/produktion/web/htdocs_final/brandwatch/brandwatch.php on line 31.

What can i do? to see just one entry of the array and how can i parse it?
thanks for help!

Comment: Can you post the code that is on line 31 of brandwatch.php?

Comment: Please post the output of `echo '<pre>'.print_r($array, true).'</pre>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really getting that json code from the request and you decode it with

```
$array = json_decode($result, true);
```

you will get an (associative) array that has the same structure as the json string (without the `true` value, you will get objects, that's why you got the Fatal Error). In that case, you can just access its fields, like so:

```
foreach ($array["results"] as $result) {
    echo "id=" . $result["id"] . ", name=" . $result["name"] . "\n";
}
```

yielding the output:

```
id=1998425622, name=Regionale Mentions_Branche
id=1998422533, name=HTP_Sponsoring
id=1998422529, name=HTP_Brand Mentions
```

Answer (score 0):

the response of `echo '<pre>'.print_r($array, true).'</pre>';`

```
 stdClass Object
    (
        [resultsTotal] => 3
        [resultsPage] => -1
        [resultsPageSize] => -1
        [results] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1998425622
                        [name] => Regionale Mentions_Branche
                        [type] => search string
                        [creationDate] => 2015-08-21T15:13:58.226+0000
                        [lastModificationDate] => 2015-08-21T15:13:58.226+0000
                        [lastModifiedUsername] => mueller@cybay.de
                        [lockedQuery] => 
                        [lockedByUsername] => 
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1998422533
                        [name] => HTP_Sponsoring
                        [type] => search string
                        [creationDate] => 2015-08-18T08:53:38.136+0000
                        [lastModificationDate] => 2015-08-18T08:53:38.136+0000
                        [lastModifiedUsername] => mueller@cybay.de
                        [lockedQuery] => 
                        [lockedByUsername] => 
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1998422529
                        [name] => HTP_Brand Mentions
                        [type] => search string
                        [creationDate] => 2015-08-18T08:41:32.699+0000
                        [lastModificationDate] => 2015-08-18T14:42:19.977+0000
                        [lastModifiedUsername] => mueller@cybay.de
                        [lockedQuery] => 
                        [lockedByUsername] => 
                    )

            )

    )
```